# Is it possible to make mat-grid-list direction to be right to left?

Tags: angular-material, right-to-left, direction

I am using mat-grid-list of Material in an Angular project.
I would like that the mat-grid-tile items direction will be in right to left order (By default the order of the items in mat-grid-list is left to right).
I would like to get help how to change it.
Thank you.
Hagai

Answer (score 0):

I found it simple.
adding an attribute dir="rtl" to mat-grid-list solved my problem.